# I have an API deployed to an Azure VM. I'd like to send all console output from this API to some cloud text storage for reading How do I do this?

Tags: azure, logging

As per the title, I just want all stdio output from this service to be sent to a cloud resource like cloudwatch logs or Azure Monitor so I can just read them in a time span.  All stdio lines should be there.

The documentation for this seems nonexistent

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what tech that API is built on and what OS your VM is hosting. But the simplest way is IMO to enable the monitoring agent on your VM. Create a Log Analytics workspace and attach your VM straight from the portal. This way you can subscribe to different sources of logs and make them appear in your LA workspace, to be queried and filtered for further analysis.
Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm

You output from your API can then within the VM be directed to either Windows EventLog or Linux syslog, which is supported out of the box in Log Analytics workspace and the monitoring agent. If your API runs in a container, say with docker, you can enable a special container monitoring solution on your created LA workspace - or you can configure docker to direct container logs to either syslog or EventLog directly.

If you run docker containers, here's a guide for configuring the logging driver: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/

If you run you API on IIS, you can simply enable IIS logs fetching on your LA workspace from the portal. However, this will only send HTTP logs and not stdout as far as I know.
If Anything else, please enhance your question.